# Populating EXTJs grid with data from postgreSQl database using ASP.net

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ExtJs and I am trying something as below.
I have created a grid inside a tab panel using ExtJs, the tab panel is placed in my aspx page. I have a table in postgreSQl data base.I am retrieving some data from the table using a query in the aspx.cs page and storing the retrieved data in a dataset.
Now I need to populate the grid inside the tab panel with this ds. The columns and header of the grid should reflect the dataset.

Please help me to complete the task. Also, a sample code will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Returning data from ASP.net to an ExtJS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221273/returning-data-from-asp-net-to-an-extjs-grid)

http://www.miamicoder.com/post/2010/07/24/More-Ext-JS-with-ASPNET-MVC-Goodies-Populating-a-GridPanel.aspx

http://osman.it/aspnet/using-extjs-grid-with-aspnet-ajax-wcf-webservices-c/