# MVC3 .Net + ExtJs 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs4

I need to know if it is possible to work with ExtJS 4 components like Grid, Combobox, etc., in the Razor Views of MVC 3 .Net. If it *is* possible, I'd also like to know where I can read a manual/tutorial or some documentation on this.

Comment: Hey, where is problem? It's javascript library, you can use it as any js scripts.

Comment: I'm not in problem with that i just ask if i can make a razor view with ExtJs4 components bc the last realease of extjs is mvc client and not just a collection of components like telerik or jqX

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on ExtJS4 Combo & ASP.NET MVC3:

http://whatisextjs.com/extjs-4-tutorial/extjs4-combo-asp-net-mvc3#more-452

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible, the Razor views will just generate normal HTML pages, so anything you can do in normal HTML, you can do in ASP.NET MVC.

P.s. check out Ext.NET, a ExtJs library for .NET. Perhaps you find it useful: http://www.ext.net/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extjs grid in mvc.
mvc - grid sample
http://nraykov.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/using-ext-js-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/

check this also [Returning data from ASP.net to an ExtJS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221273/returning-data-from-asp-net-to-an-extjs-grid)